# Folding c.ode in python function

Tags: python, vim

Let's say I have a python function like this:

```
class Something:
    def my_function(...): <---- start fold
        ...
        return None       <---- end fold
    def my_function2(...):
        ...
```

If I am on the first function line, `def my_function` -- and let's suppose that function is ~50 locs, how would I fold that function in vim? The first thing I thought of doing is `zf/return` -- but this is quite flawed, as (1) lots of functions won't have return statements; or event more common, there will be multiple return statements within a single function.

What would be the best way to do this?

(StackOverflow doesn't allow the word 'code' in a post??)

Comment: There's overlap, but you might try asking in [vi.se].

Answer (score 0):

Try `zf]M`. `]M` should act as a motion to take you to the end of the current method.

Comment: that's what I thought too, but if there are no line breaks between the two functions it doesn't work. Actually, I've tried that a bit more and it's just about useless with python (I think it requires the function to start the line so cannot be a method within a class...)

Comment: PEP-8 recommends a blank line between functions.

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't matter in this case. The `]]` goes all the way up until the next function that starts a line, i.e., `r'^def'` -- at least that's my understanding through trial-and-error of what `]]` is doing as it relates to `ft=python`.

Comment: `def` isn't at the beginning of the line, it's indented because this is inside a class definition.

Comment: Ah, I see the example has been changed so they are now embedded in a class.

Comment: Updated with something that should be method-aware.

Answer (score 0):

Try `:set foldmethod=indent`. It may work for you. [VimWiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Syntax_folding_of_Python_files) can be quite helpful though.

The problem with python is the lack of explicit block delimiters. So you may want to use some plugins like [SimpylFold](https://github.com/tmhedberg/SimpylFold)